# Alignment Issue in .csv File

Tags: java, csv

I am working on writing of data into CSV file using Java. How can I give left alignment to each column in CSV File?

```
public class WriteToFileCsv
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("WriteTest.csv");
       PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw);

       out.print("This");
       out.print(",");
       out.print("is");
       out.print(",");

       out.print("It's");
       out.print(",");
       out.print("really");
       out.print(",");

       out.flush();      
       out.close();
       fw.close();       
    }
}
```

Comment: *"How can I give left alignment to each column in CSV File?"*  Why would you want to?  It seems you want this CSV to be 'easily human readable', whereas that is not the intent of CSV.

Comment: I highly recommend using a library such as OpenCSV for proper creation of CSV files. As Andrew stated, there are no methods for proper alignment of the file, because CSV is intended to be readable for machines, not for humans.

Comment: **CSV** files contain just comma seperated values. `This,isIts's,really` in your case and this is all information it can have, really. **CSV** files can be viewed using notepad, gedit, etc and you will see just comma seperated values that you set. If you really want it to store styling information, you should save it as **xls**, **xlsx**, or any other format that supports styling.

Comment: or just go for Fixed-Length Format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose a width for the columns, e.g. `10`, and then use [`format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
int width = 10;
String columnFormat = "%-" + width + "s";
out.format(columnFormat, "This");
out.print(",");
out.format(columnFormat, "is");
out.print(",");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to [Fixed-Length data format](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.hpl.doc/hplmst135.htm).
CSV is not meant to have alignment.

Answer (score 0):

To have alignment in you csv file you need to create an excel file.  Try Apache POI

http://poi.apache.org/